# zsh: Splitting a path that may not have an extension

Tags: zsh, filenames, filepath

In a `zsh` script, I want to split the filename component of a path into three pieces: the root, the `.` separator (that may not be there), and the extension.  Another process is going to modify the pieces and join them back together.

Determining whether the input path has a `.` was a bit more complicated than
expected.  So far this is the best answer I've found:

```
split=( "${path:r}" "${${path#${path:r}}:+.}" "${path:e}" )
```

It uses `zsh`'s `r` and `e` parameter flags to get the root and extension;
those parts work well.  The more cryptic expansion for the middle component is
essentially comparing the path root and the original path. If they are the
same, then there is no separator and the value is set to an empty string.
Otherwise it is set to a period.

It seems there should be an easier option than a three-part nested
substitution.  Is there a flag or something simple that I'm missing, or an SO
post that my searches aren't finding?

---

Code for testing:

```
#!/bin/zsh
testsplit() {
  local path=$1
  local split=( "${path:r}" "${${path#${path:r}}:+.}" "${path:e}" )

  print "input:    [$path]"
  print "split[${#split}]:" "[${(@)^split}]"

  # tests: does rejoined path match input; is second element '.' or empty
  [[ ${(j::)split} == $path && ${split[2]:-.} == '.' ]]
}
typeset -a testpaths=(
  "base.ext"
  "endsindot."
  "no_ext"
  "/a.b/c.d/e"
  "/a.b/c.d/e."
  "/a.b/c.d/e.f"
  "/has/s p aces  /before . after"
  $"/*/'and?[sdf]\n>\t\tpat.tern[^r\`ty&]///*/notreal.d"
)
integer ecount=0
print '.'
for path in ${testpaths}; do
  testsplit "$path"
  (($?)) && ((++ecount)) && print "=== ERROR ==="
  print '.'
done
print "Error count: [$ecount]."
((ecount)) && print "=== ERRORS FOUND ==="
```

Output:

```
.
input:    [base.ext]
split[3]: [base] [.] [ext]
.
input:    [endsindot.]
split[3]: [endsindot] [.] []
.
input:    [no_ext]
split[3]: [no_ext] [] []
.
input:    [/a.b/c.d/e]
split[3]: [/a.b/c.d/e] [] []
.
input:    [/a.b/c.d/e.]
split[3]: [/a.b/c.d/e] [.] []
.
input:    [/a.b/c.d/e.f]
split[3]: [/a.b/c.d/e] [.] [f]
.
input:    [/has/s p aces  /before . after]
split[3]: [/has/s p aces  /before ] [.] [ after]
.
input:    [$/*/'and?[sdf]
>       pat.tern[^r`ty&]///*/notreal.d]
split[3]: [$/*/'and?[sdf]
>       pat.tern[^r`ty&]///*/notreal] [.] [d]
.
Error count: [0].
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the requirement: Assuming that the input is `/a.b/c.d/e` what output would you expect?

Comment: @user1934428 - I only need to split the filename component of the path, so directories are included with the root.  Your example would be treated as a filename without an extension: `split=( '/a.b/c.d/e' '' '' )`.   I added the expected output from the test code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems there should be an easier option than a three-part nested substitution.

Perhaps, but unfortunately, there really isn't.

Here's how I would do it, but again, a nested substitution cannot be avoided:

```sh
% split() { 
  local split=( "$1:r" "${${1#$1:r}[1]}" "$1:e" )
  print "${(q@)split}"
}
% split foo.orig.c 
foo.orig . c
% split dir.c/foo 
dir.c/foo '' ''
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this; looks like we're stuck with the complicated answesr for now. I wonder if the zsh team has ever considered a `:d` (dot) parameter flag or something similar.    I have a slight preference for my version of the nested substitution since the variable is only listed twice, but your version is probably easier for people to understand.

Comment: You can always ask the devs directly on the mailing list: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/mlist.html

Comment: Since length/repetition is a concern for you, I've now shortened the code a bit. :)

Comment: That's now my favorite version - less repetition, and it doesn't make any assumptions about the delimiter (even though we know it's always `.`). Thanks!